# Microcontroller for high speed ADC and large data storage or how to?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, adc

I need to sample a voltage signal at relatively high speed (approx. 1 Msps max). So far, STM32H7 series looks good for this. There are two problems I am facing here.

1. The total data reading time is quite long (100s~). Even with gradual decrease of the sampling rate, the total data size may end up in a few megabytes. The current MCUs do not seem to have such large SRAM.
2. The datasheet and some other forums suggest that DMA from the ADC is possible but I could not find any sample or guideline on how to do that. Recording data with CPU intervention would not be fast enough.

So, how can I use DMA to sample signal at high speed? Any sample project I can refer to would be most appreciated. And would it be possible to do the same with an extra SRAM connected to SPI bus?

I am sure the question is very elementary and I am probably missing a technical term somewhere that I should search with. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: ST provides example codes and a documented HAL. There must be examples for how to sample ADC with DMA. And there is no point having 100MB of RAM at least not on SPI bus. Write the data to USB memory or SD card.

Comment: @Justme I am looking for such sample codes, haven't found yet. Putting the data on a SD card was my first thought but I doubt an SD card would be fast enough to keep up with 1Msps speed.

Comment: Why do you doubt an SD card can't transfer 1 Msps? Even cheapest cards I can currently get just by walking to nearest grocery store or supermarket can transfer tens of megabytes per second. Seems to be a 32GB Class 10 / UHS-I Speed Class 1 (U1) card, boasting 100 MB/s and suitable for Full HD video recording. Should store a measly 2MB/s of 1Msps data just fine.

Comment: @Justme I looked if DMA to SD card is possible but couldn't find any example of such. An SD card is definitely capable of 2MB/s write operation but if the ADC data has to go through CPU, a 550 MHz CPU may not be able to keep up with 1 Msps. If could you provide any example of DMA with SD card, please?

Comment: Do you realy need to store data in memory ? There is easy way to send them to PC.

Comment: @MichalDudka, I have been fumbling around to see if I can use DMA to send directly to PC. I only need 1 Msps rate, the data can be anywhere.

Comment: you can use FTDI FT232H (2232H or 4232H). You can simply send data out STM32 by UART (speed limited by FTDI to 12Mbit/s - about 1MByte/s). If this is not enought you can also use 8bit paralel interface (asynchronous up to 8MB/s), which can be driven from STM32 by DMA to GPIO transfer, or (better) adapting FMC/FSMC for this purpose. And you can also use FT245 synchronous interface (up to about 35MB/s) with STM32H7 with PSSI peripheral (in this case you probably slightly violate timings, because STM32H750 PSSI transmit speed is limited to 50MHz clock and FTDI generate 60MHz).